# r data.frame to a named list

Tags: r, list, data.table, converters

I want an easy way to convert a data.table or tibble into a named list.
I'm guessing it could be down with  purrr, nest and split. This is for an options list in shiny.

There are similar question, but did not find any like this.

```
d <- tidyr::tribble(
  ~key,  ~value,
  'a',        1,
  'b',        2,
  'c',        3
)

result <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
```

Comment: You've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60028873/5325862), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19265172/5325862), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10432993/5325862)?

Comment: @Camille  I saw the last one, but the first two you mention would also work.

Comment: After trying this with shiny selectInput, the with(df, setNames(Score, Words)) from @tmfmnk is what worked.  So thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to `deframe` to create a named `vector` and then use `as.list`. to convert each element as a `list` element

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
deframe(d) %>%
   as.list
```

---

Or in `base R` with `split`

```
with(d, split(value, key))
```

Comment: `split` worked nicely to convert a data frame back into a named list for me.